# How can I quickly search my code using unix?

Tags: unix, search, indexing

I frequently search for a token, perhaps a function name, throughout my codebase. My traditional method would be to grep for the term itself. However, the codebase is so large that I can't do this efficiently (it takes minutes).

Is there a way to do this efficiently?

ack (which ignores irrelevent files such as revision control files) is still too slow. ctags only finds declarations, which isn't what I need. I thought something like strigi might work, but I haven't tried it.

I'm on linux, using vim and the GNU toolchain, on a largely C++ codebase.

Comment: I typically use find + grep for a single code base, or on Mac OS X I use Spotlight to search over multiple code bases, which is almost instantaneous (it's indexed) - is there some equivalent to Spotlight for Linux, I wonder ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `find` and `fgrep`.  A decent `find` will restrict the set to files matching some set of criteria, and `fgrep` will search within each file.  Note that `fgrep` will be faster than `grep`.

You could also use an IDE's code indexing features.  For example, Eclipse will allow you to go to a function's declaration, and it builds the relevant set in the background while you work.  Even vim 7 has some such features, although I don't remember exactly what it does beyond code completion.

Comment: Wow, fgrep is a lot faster than grep, like 6 times faster. That said, I'm really looking for some kind of indexing - I don't want to have to specify the file type (I'm working with C++, but found a token I was looking for in a .idl file).

Comment: @Paul Biggar: The equivalent of Spotlight for Linux is called Beagle.  You could also use slocate or rlocate.  rlocate might be better for this situation.