# How can I quickly search my code using Windows?

Tags: windows, search, indexing

I've got the same problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250832/how-can-i-quickly-search-my-code-using-unix), except in Windows. Our product has a 100+ MB code base, and searching for stuff in there takes an awful amount of time (several minutes). It's nice when you can narrow your search to a specific subfolder, but that isn't always possible.

I was wondering if there is some tool that would make it faster, probably by indexing. Accuracy is paramount, if a substring exists somewhere, it must be found, even if the file is not indexed or the index is out of date. Also it would be ideal if `.svn` folders would be ignored when searching.

Failing that, I was wondering if I could make something like that myself. Is there maybe a ready made indexing engine available for such tasks? I was wondering about Windows Indexing Service (or whatever it is called these days), but so far my experience with it (the Windows standard file search facility) has been rather dismal, with it often missing files that were right in front of its nose.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have seen Window Indexing service miss files too, but I haven't checked KBs or user forums for explanations. I'm glad to see it confirmed that it's not just me ;-)!

There look to be alot of file index programs available, I would be surprised if you can't find one that meets your needs (although, see later).

Here are some things to consider:

If your team is using an IDE, isn't there an index feature/plug-in? (none of the SVNs provide Indexing capabilites?). **Also**, add some tags to your question so this will be seen by other windows developers using the same dev enviorment that you are using.

The SO link you provided mentions several options: slocate, rlocate, and I found mlocate. The wikipedia page for slocate says 
[Locate32 for Windows Windows analog of GNU locate with GUI, released under GNU license](http://www.locate32.net/)
which seems to meet your main requirement. Looking at the screen shots with the multi-tab interface (one labeled advanced) would give me hope that you can exclude svn (at least from results, possibly from what is indexed).

Your requirement for

> if a substring exists somewhere, it
>   must be found, even if the file is not
>   indexed or the index is out of date.

seems contradictory. For the substring requirement, I can see many indexing programs ignore c lang syntax elements ( {([])}, etc), and, for example, 'then' is either removed because it is considered a noise word, or that it gets stemmed-down to 'the' and THEN is removed because it is noise word.

To get to 'must be found', and *really* be sure, you would have to develop a test suite to see what the index program is doing for anything that is corner case. (For a 100 MB code base, not out of the question, especially since you are considering rolling your own).

Finally 'even if the file is not indexed ...'. Well, you either use an index or your don't (obviously). Unfortunately, for your requirement, while rlocate is looking for changes all the time, slocate (on Unix) doesn't seem to. Probably if you read/check on the docs or user forums for locate32 you'll get the answers you need.

Rlocate would give you what you need, but from an [rlocate page](http://rlocate.sourceforge.net/#ports) 'rlocate will work only on Linux with version 2.6.'. mlocate doesn't seem to be have a Windows port either only.

Finally here is a link I found that is interesting about mlocate : [mlocate vs rlocate](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:7pt4Z2UTy30J%3awww.redhat.com/archives/rhl-devel-list/2006-February/msg01060.html%20rlocate&cd=5&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&source=www.google.com). This is the google cache, because the redhat.com said 'not available'.

Comment: "even if the file is not indexed or the index is out of date" presumably means that the index stores metadata such as the modification date, the full list of files is gotten from the directory, and for each file the index is used if the metadata matches and otherwise the file is opened and a linear search is executed (and maybe the index is updated in the process).

Comment: @BenVoigt : I took his phrase to mean, not indexed because either  only the dev copy has been changed (maybe not written to file yet?) (or not checked in) OR the indexer cycle has not picked up the change yet. "Never say 'Never'" in a specification (unless you **really** mean it). But specifications are a whole other subject. ;-) Thanks for your alternate insight!

Comment: Doah, he didn't say never, but "it must be found" (sheepish look) ;-%, which is also pretty unforgiving as a term in a use-case. It's late, G-night!

Comment: I really meant it for the cases when the indexer hasn't gotten around to indexing the file. To put it in other words - the results of the indexed search should be the same as for a simple full search (like what I'm doing now), except faster.  And to put it in other words yet - if a file contains the substring I've entered, it should be in the search results, no excuses.

Comment: Oh, and also I meant that the whole thing would be **local** on my own machine. I don't want to search the latest checked in code or something like that. Just folders on my own local machine.

Comment: Ah, for the IDEs - we're developing programs in at least 3 different IDEs and languages, so this is kinda IDE-agnostic.

Comment: So I guess you need to either dig in on the Locate32 (for windows) documentation OR post to that apps forums OR see if there is a locate32 tag here on SO ;-). That is certainly the path of least resistance. Good luck! and let us know if it works for you.